# Extract whole number between 2 slashes

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract id, which is a whole number from a url, for example:

`http://example.com/email/verify/106/8be57f01ac84747886acd7ae88c888112135fc7a`

I'd like to extract only `106` from the string in PHP. <s>The only dynamic variables in the URL would be the domain and the hash after `106/`</s> The domain, id, and hash after `106/` are all dynamic.

I've tried `preg_match_all('!\d+!', $url, $result)`, but it matches all number in string.

Any tips?

Comment: `preg_match_all('!/(\d+)/!', $url, $result)` and get `$result[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `\b\d+\b` might be specific enough here:

```
$url = "http://example.com/email/verify/106/8be57f01ac84747886acd7ae88c888112135fc7a";
preg_match_all('/\b\d+\b/', $url, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 106
)
```

Comment: I'm getting `preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

Comment: Reload your page.

Comment: Oops yep, that does work, opcache was caching my code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will works.

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //"http://example.com/email/verify/106/8be57f01ac84747886acd7ae88c888112135fc7a";
$str = explode('/',$url);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($str);

$id = $str[5]; // 106
```